Why Does C# Syntax Treat ptr = null Differently from Pointer Dereferencing in C++?
In C++, we can use ptr = nullptr to change the pointer itself and *ptr to modify the object the pointer references. For example:
int* ptr = new int(5);

*ptr = 10;  // Modifies the object
ptr = nullptr;  // Changes the pointer itself

In C#, we have similar scenarios with references. For instance:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");

sb.Append(" World");  // Modifies the object
sb = null;  // Sets the reference to null

My question is about the syntax and why it behaves differently. Specifically:

When I use sb.Append(), it operates on the object sb points to, not the reference itself.

When I use sb = null, it sets the reference to null, but doesn't affect the object.


Why doesn't the syntax of sb = null in C# get interpreted as setting the object to null, similar to how ptr = nullptr works in C++? Or in other words, why don't I have to dereference sb to call the Append() method? In C#, why isn't there a need to explicitly dereference the reference to perform operations on the object and how does it know when to dereference a pointer and when to manipulate it directly?
I have read up on this, but haven't found a good explanation. All that I have learned till now is that C# probably doesn't allow us to dereference explicitly but isn't that very puzzling? Like conceptually I might know that sb = null cannot set the referenced pointer to null but isn't the syntax saying otherwise or at least is unambiguous?
I'm looking for clarity on why the syntax in C# doesn't directly map to pointer manipulation in C++ and how the language ensures this distinction.

My question is about the syntax and why it behaves differently -- Because C# has nothing to do with C++.  They are two different computer languages.  Just because one resembles the other doesn't mean you can figure one language out by using the other's idioms and practices.

in C# there's the notion of "reference-types", which pretty much covers it. You don't need to de-reference any pointer in C#, because pointers rarely even exist (they do, though). Instead you usually deal with objects by their respective references. So having said this, your questions is based on different notions, which simply doesn't apply in c#.

possible duplicate of Difference between pointer in C++ and reference type in C#

Seems like comparing apples to oranges. In C++ you have references too, so with a StringBuilder& sb you can write sb.Append(" World");. (Unlike pointers though, a C++ reference is not nullable, and you don't use new).

I dont understand the difference you see. In both cases xyz = null / nullptr; leaves the object unchanged.

"similar to how ptr = nullptr works in C++? " in C++ ptr = nullptr;  does nothing to the integer just like sb = null; (I suppose, I dont know C#) does nothing to the actual Stringbuilder object

though I agree with others. It unclear why you expect two different languages to be the same. "C# doesn't directly map to pointer manipulation in C++" why would it?

I suggest to read about value- vs reference-semantics. I hope this will shed some light on the issue for you

@463035818_is_not_an_ai value-types and reference-types don't really apply here as well, as this implies one being pointers, the other objects.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain why would it not apply? C++ has value-semantics, C# seems to have reference semantics. I didnt talk about "value-types and reference-types" but about value- vs reference-semantics generally, which I believe will help OP to undstand the difference between languages when they read about it.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai exactly, it's about semantics, not syntax. On a semantic level Value-types don't need pointer-arithemtic, nor do referency-types. And as you said: C++ has value-types (structs) as well, although it has this notion of pointers. So value- and reference-semantics exist in C++ as well

@MakePeaceGreatAgain really sorry, but I do not see how anything you write relates to my comment about val vs ref semantics.

At the memory level C# and C++ behave very very differently (and other areas too), even new doesn't do the same things. Objects have different lifecycles, so your question in a sense doesn't make sense. (explicit memory managment vs. Garbage collection, value vs reference semantics).

Thank you for all your comments, they are pretty helpful. One thing that I'd like to mention is I am not expecting the two languages to behave the same way. I am just trying to describe what exactly is confusing me: how does it know that sb = null is setting the reference null and not trying to set the object null? Like why doesn't it automatically dereference (or try to dereference and give an error or something) at sb = null. How does it know it's the reference being set to null and not the referenced object?

Also, pardon my ignorance: I was under the impression that references and pointers are the same thing. Which I now understand they aren't, but the original question still stands: how does it know when to dereference and when not to? I want to understand the syntax.

@aim in c++ a pointer is a type, and operations on a variable of a pointer type will only affect the pointer, one of the operations is a dereference operator, which when applied to a pointer returns a reference to the object which is another type (reference type), and any modification to the reference object modifies the actual object .... you need to understand that those are 2 different types, and operations on a variable depends on its type.

For example x += 1 depends on the type of x, if x is a pointer type int* the pointer is incremented , but if x is a reference type int& then the underlying refered-to object is incremented, you can convert between pointer and a refernce by those three operators * and & and -> (the last one is like (*x). but its two letters instead of 4 )

Oh this explains a lot, I cannot believe I never knew that pointers and references were different things. Sorry for being redundant: but how does C# know that sb = null is trying to set the reference null and not the referenced object? (If sb is a reference, and sb.Append() changes the referenced object, shouldn't sb = null also attempt to set the referenced object to null?)

@aim in C++ you can have a pointer to a pointer ... or a reference to a pointer, etc .... in C# you have a reference and values that's it, it has nothing to do with C++ pointer or refrence, it is just a name ..... assignment to reference types modifies the reference whereas assignment to value types modifies the values, and you have a weird reference to value type ( ref ) wich has the same symantics as a value type except they are done on the refered-to object (similar to c++ references)

This is only for the assignment operator, don't try to infer operator behavior from different language, in C# the dot operator calls a function on the refered-to object, this is different than assignment which modifies the reference, not the object ....  both operators modify the object in C++ but not in C#, don't infer operators from one language to another.

Trying to correlate C# idioms to C++ idioms will only show that the languages are different, and the the constructs in the languages have little correspondence between each other — just some similarities, and language specific jargon used with different semantics.  (Making it confusing to talk about both languages using each language's jargon.)

So anytime I try to use the '=' operator it will modify the reference, and when I use the '.' operator it modifies the referenced object. Is that correct?
P.S thank you everyone for the help, really clarified a lot on the way.

@aim for reference types in C# yes, for value types and ref of value types, no ... again it depends on the object type

@aim for example int in C# is a value type, assigning to it modifies the object, whereas String is a reference type, assignment to it modifies the reference.

Thank you so much, issue resolved. Could you also please explain how ref of value types work? Would be very thankful.

I think msdn is best source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref but in short since value types are passed around by value ie: by copy, the ref keyword allows you to create a .... reference to a value .... that when the reference is modified (by assignment) it modified the refered-to value .... because that's how this type is defined ... very useful in creating an out parameter or modifying an element in a list, it is just an alias, a different way to modify the original object, a lot similar to C++ references.

Part of the design philosophy of C# (and some other languages) is to discourage (or prevent) as many operations on pointers as possible  (since they are considered "bad" or "unsafe").     References in C# have some features in common with C++ pointers, some features in common with C++ references, and some additional restrictions on both.  So the basic answer to your question is "because the designers of C# chose to do it in a way that differs from C++".     Opinions vary as to whether the C# approach is better or worse than the C++ approach (there are advantages and disadvantages, either way).

@AhmedAEK I'd avoid talking about .NET strings in this context because they're weird (technically reference types but act like value types).

It's actually not so much different to C++ in syntax. Conceptually, reference type variables in C# and pointers in C++ do share a common base, even though there are quite a few detail differences. But since you asked about the syntax, the case is easier:
In C++ you would write:
StringBuilder* sb = new StringBuilder();
(*sb).Append(...);
sb = nullptr; // well, rather delete first, but we don't care here.

The (*sb).Append() is usually abbreviated as sb->Append(). And now we're already very close to C#, because you can just think that in C#, the -> operator is also just written as .. It's just that the compiler is "smart" enough to know whether the member-access operator has a reference type or a value type on its left side.

Thank you so much for your response. Just a little questions though: can we say that the '=' operator modifies the reference but for the '.' operator, the compiler figures out if the subsequent method is for the reference or for the referenced object and then runs accordingly?

Mostly, yes. If the object is a reference type (a class) then the . operation is always on the referenced object. Only if the object is a value type (a struct, or a simple type like int), then the value may change (we don't call it reference in that case). This however is also a very rare case, since most struct types are designed to be unmodifiable. So for almost all practical cases, you can assume that the . operator works on the referenced object.
